# HTML List Object Styling doesn't apply to the whole block

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar and trying to follow https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_gray.
My navigation bar isn't working as expected. When I hover over a list object, I only see the text and its small background change colour, not the whole block. How do I make the whole block change colour?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navigation Bar-->
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="weather.html">Weather</a></li>
        <li><a href="time.html">World Time</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Navigation Bar End-->
</body>
</html>
```

default.css:

```
/*Importing Fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,900');
/*Finish Import*/

#navbar{
    font-family: "Raleway SemiBold", serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #13006e;
    display: block;
}

#navbar li {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: #008000;
}
```

Thanks!
Neeron.

Comment: You need to add li a{display:block} like the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add just **a** tag to **navbar li**.

```css
/*Importing Fonts*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,900');
/*Finish Import*/

#navbar{
    font-family: "Raleway SemiBold", serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #13006e;
    display: block;
}

#navbar li a{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-color: #008000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
    <title>My Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navigation Bar-->
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="weather.html">Weather</a></li>
        <li><a href="time.html">World Time</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Navigation Bar End-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could you explain why that is so? I believe it is the "hover" but not declaring when it isn't "hovering". Am I right?